# How to work with variables from .mat files regarding passing them to Matlab functions in C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-compiler

So I needed to read some variables from a .mat file using my C++ code, so I naturally used the C Matrix API (for example: `mat.h`) to get access to functions like `matOpen` or `matGetVariable` and it stores said variables in `mxArray` variables

Thing is, I need these said variables to use in my generated Matlab functions Matlab functions I compiled as C++ shared libraries and now use in C++.
However, these functions only accept `mwArray` not `mxArray` variables.
Is there a way around this?
There has to be, but I really can't see it atm, so any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If your main code is in C++ and you just need to read `.mat` files to get the data, then you don't need to call MATLAB's API just for that. That are libraries that can read `.mat` files. I can't recommend a particular one now because it's been a few years since I last opened a MATLAB file, but you should be able to find one.

Comment: I can't find any libraries that store the variables from the `.mat` files into `mwArray` variables. I have installed the Matio library and it works, but it sadly only stores the from the `.mat` files into `matvar_t*` and not `mwArray`. So I am stuck with the same problem here.